# How can I run the jQuery preview upload button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, jquery-plugins

I can preview many images without any problem. But I don't know how I can get the value of the image clicked on the upload section and send it with ajax?

```
<div>
    <input type="file" name="file[]" id="images" multiple />
    </div>
    
    <ul id="prewiew">
    
    </ul>
    
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
      
       $('#images').on('change', function (e) { 

           //It prints the added pictures one by one on the page with a loop.
           var files = e.target.files;
                   
            $.each(files, function (i, file) {        
                     
               var reader = new FileReader();
               reader.readAsDataURL(file);
               reader.onload = function (e) {
                            
               var template = '<li>' +
               '<img src="' + e.target.result + '" width="50" height="50"> ' +
               '<label>' + file.name + file.size + '</label> <input type="text" name="title">' +
               ' <button  class="btn btn-sm btn-info upload">Yükle</button>' +           
               '</li>';
    
               $("#prewiew").append(template);
               $("#resim").val('');
            }
    
          });
                  
     });
   

     $(document).on("click", ".upload", function () {

         //How can I receive and transfer data when the button is clicked? 

         var file = $(this).closest("img");
         var data= new FormData();     
         data.append("ImageFile", file); 
       
         $.ajax({
             url: '/Home/ImagePost/',
             type: 'POST',
             data: data,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             success: function () {
    
             },
    
         });
    
     });
```

[image]

Summary: I am previewing multiple images. I want to send the previewed picture by pressing the upload button.

Comment: Please clarify your scenario. You have multiple images on your page, with buttons under them, and you want to post the picture whose button you clicked?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple trick here:

1. Hide your input field.
2. Add click event to that button in which you need to click on hidden input dynamically.

Here is the working example:

```js
$('button').click(function () {
    $('input').click();
    // Your ajax code 
});
```

```css
input {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
    <img src="anonim.jpg" width="100" height="50" />
    <input type="file" name="somename" size="chars">
    <button>Upload</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can reread the question.Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @Slmo, before updating, your question was about how to upload the image without using `input` or something like this. Ok, let me have a look at the updated one.

Comment: I wanted to keep the subject short. I updated it when I realized it was misunderstood. Thank you